# Programmatically retrieve all repositories under my Github account using Jgit

Tags: java, github, jgit

I'm having a bit of a challenge with the JGit client. I'm embedding it in a Java App & I'd like to fetch all the repositories under an account on Github and display them. Also to add on, can I create a repository direct on Github using JGit. Like Create a Remote Repository?

I've gone through this [link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) but it seems generic to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: please post your code, and errors you got.

Comment: @Sachith I would have but I practically don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Sachith you don't need an api to retrieve it. you can do it with a simple Java url request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [List user repositories API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories) is something you can call from any language (including Java) and is not related to JGit.

```
GET /users/:username/repos
```

An example of Java library making those calls would be "[GitHub API for Java](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/index.html) ", and its [`java.org.kohsuke.github.GHPerson.java#listRepositories()`](https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api/blob/9ab6d570193dc381a0cda7cc4991f471499dcf24/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github/GHPerson.java#L70-L89) method

```
new PagedIterator<GHRepository>(
   root.retrieve().asIterator("/users/" + login + "/repos?per_page=" + pageSize, 
                              GHRepository[].class, pageSize))
```

Once you get the url for those user repos, you can create JGit repos out of them.

Comment: And yes, you can create repos too: https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api/blob/14dcb37ee1ea225b73b548faae313ab512ae69a4/src/site/markdown/index.md#sample-usage

Comment: That makes sense now. thanks. Didnt even use the API, just called directly from URL#openStream()

Answer (score 1):

I also doing that same Requirement To get  List of repositories of a particular user
Try this one you will get All repositories  of that user
//Here name means username of GitHub account

```
public Collection<AuthMsg> getRepos(String name) {

    String url = "https://api.github.com/users/"+name+"/repos";

    String data = getJSON(url);
    System.out.println(data);

    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<AuthMsg>>(){}.getType();
    Collection<AuthMsg> enums = new Gson().fromJson(data, collectionType);

    return enums;

}
```

//getJson method

```
public String getJSON(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection c = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {                                      
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
       if (c != null) {
          try {
              c.disconnect();
          } catch (Exception ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

//AuthMsg Class

```
public class AuthMsg {
//"name" which is in json what we get from url
@SerializedName("name")
private String repository;

/**
 * @return the repository
 */
public String getRepository() {
    return repository;
}

/**
 * @param repository the repository to set
 */
public void setRepository(String repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

}